# Upgrading TWC modem/router with 192.168.0.1 default address on home network with existing Trendnet wired router set to 192.168.2.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I have a home network with a Trendnet TW100-S4W1CA wired router with a base address of 192.168.2.1, DHCP turned on with a range of 192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.100, subnet 255.255.255.0. It is connected to my 5-year old TWC digital phone/cable modem. I don't know if there is any IP address (on my network) for this. I have a wireless access point with DHCP turned on with a range of 192.168.2.101 - 192.168.2.255, subnet 255.255.255.0. This all works great.

I was at the TWC store recently and they gave me a newer modem to increase bandwidth (ARRIS Touchstone DOCSIS 3.0 Gateways). I see this new modem has a built-in wireless router as well as being a wired router. The built-in wireless says it is pre-set to 192.168.0.1.

I am at a loss as to how this can be integrated with my "2" net (192.168.2.x).

If I could ignore the wireless feature of the new cable modem or turn it off that would be fine too. I would like to replace the cable modem, but I'm afraid if I do I'll totally mess up everything I have in place.

Has anyone been in this situation, and/or can offer advice?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: You have _both_ the router and the AP acting as DHCP servers? **Why?**

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should have *one* router in such a network, at the edge. Additional layers will greatly confuse things, especially if dealing with stupidly-locked-down modems that I've heard of.

This means that the TW100 needs to be configured as a bridge, so that it won't do any routing or NAT anymore. (It will become a plain Ethernet switch.) If there's no "bridge" option, then connect the modem to one of TW100's **LAN** ports, it'll be the same.

The wireless AP should also be working as a bridge, no routing, no NAT. I'm sure most APs work in bridge mode by default, but double-check just in case.

Second, now that the entire LAN is bridged together, you must have *at most one* DHCP server in it. Pick one device that would serve DHCP (usually the router, but not required), configure the 192.168.2.x range in it, and disable "DHCP server" in all other devices.